# How Would I Write A Function Requiring Sender to Hold an ERC20 to Use Function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract

Does anyone know how to create a function that requires sender to have at least one token to use the function? For example, to require sender's balance to have an ether, I'd use:

```
require(balances[msg.sender] >= 1 ether);
```

How would I instead create a requirement on msg.senders ERC20 balance of a particular token that was created through the contract they're interacting with? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
token = IERC20(tokenContractAddress);
// tokens, like ethers, are usually 18 decimal places
// we use ether keyword here just to significant
// the number of decimals in the price
require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1 ether)
```

Grab a copy of [IERC20 interface definition here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol).

Comment: Thanks for the response. If  I understand correctly, I'd need to run this "require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender)" in a function of a separate contract that imports my first ERC20 contract since it needs the "tokenContractAddress"?

Comment: Correct, you need refer to the token, of which balance you want to know, by its address and interface.